# Any comprehensive material to revise the mathematics

Tags: probability, reference-request, polynomials, permutations, education

I left school long back and so my mathematics knowledge also fades out.

I am trying hard to re-collect the basics about  log / permutaion / combination / probability / polynomial equations.

I tried to get materials in internet but could not find something that is useful and can be bookmarked for any future reference.

I found one for Log. It is not very in detail.. But it gives an idea what is log is (copied one below) http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/m111s02/paklog.html

Can someone help to identify similar simple materials for other mathematical concepts

Thank you for reading the post!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, for permutations, combinations and some probability Ivan Niven's The Mathematics of Choice is a book I have found useful.